# Oracle PLSQL - Replace special characters only when between double quotes

Tags: oracle, plsql

can you please help ? I need to replace special characters chr(13) || chr(10) with an empty line in a clob, but only when it's between double quotes chr(34). Is there a way to do that with REGEXP_REPLACE ?

Thank you
Anja

Answer (score 1):

> I need to replace special characters chr(13) || chr(10) with an empty line in a clob, but only when it's between double quotes chr(34).

If you mean when it is immediately between double quotes then:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(
         value,
         '"'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||'"',
         '"'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||'"'
       ) AS updated_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value CLOB);

INSERT INTO table_name (value)
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB()||'aaa"'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||'"bbb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB()||RPAD('"', 4000, 'a') ||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||LPAD('"', 4000, 'b') FROM DUAL;
```

| UPDATED_VALUE |
| --- |
| aaa" "bbb |
| "aaa<repeated...>aaa bbb<repeated...>bbb" |

If you mean when there is a quote somewhere before and somewhere after then find the sub-string from the first to the last quote and replace CR-LF characters between those two bounds:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN INSTR(value, '"', 1) < INSTR(value, '"', -1)
       THEN SUBSTR(
              value,
              1,
              INSTR(value, '"', 1)
            )
            || REPLACE(
              SUBSTR(
                value,
                INSTR(value, '"', 1) + 1,
                INSTR(value, '"', -1) - INSTR(value, '"', 1)
              ),
              CHR(13)||CHR(10),
              CHR(13)||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||CHR(10)
            )
            || SUBSTR(
              value,
              INSTR(value, '"', -1)
            )
       ELSE value
       END AS updated_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| UPDATED_VALUE |
| --- |
| aaa" ""bbb |
| "aaa<repeated...>aaa bbb<repeated...>bbb"" |

If you want to match opening and closing quotes and only replace between them then you cannot do that using simple string functions (or regular expressions) and should write a proper parser (in either PL/SQL or another language) to iterate over the string and count quotes and replace CR-LF when the number of preceding quotes is odd.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MUOk5DHK)

Comment: To match opening and closing quotes, you can split the string on the " using classical recursive query with connect by and apply the replace only to the even levels, and eventually re-assemblying the results with LISTAGG...

Comment: @p3consulting You cannot use `LISTAGG` as the OP has a `CLOB`. Yes, I could write a recursive (rather than hierarchical) query to solve the problem of opening and closing quotes but the OP's question is ambiguous as to whether that is actually the problem or not that I've just given them solutions to the two simplest interpretations to their problem.

Comment: indeed, I didn't pay attention to the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

SQL solution for CLOB and replacing only in matching double quotes, trying to minimize the scanning cost of the CLOB:

```
with strings(id, str) as (
    select 1, EMPTY_CLOB()|| 'ajktajlt"' || chr(13) || chr(10) || '"zjgljglkJ' from dual union all
    select 2, EMPTY_CLOB()|| 'ajktajlt' || chr(13) || chr(10) || '"zjgljglkJ' from dual union all
    select 3, EMPTY_CLOB()|| 'ajktajlt' || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'zjgljglkJ' from dual union all
    select 4, EMPTY_CLOB()|| 'ajktajlt"' || chr(13) || chr(10) from dual union all
    select 5, EMPTY_CLOB()|| chr(13) || chr(10) || '"zjgljglkJ' from dual -- union all
),
findquotes(id, lvl, remaining, result, endpos) as (
    select id, 1, 
        substr(str, instr(str, '"', 1)+1) as remaining,
        case when instr(str, '"', 1) > 0 then substr(str, 1, instr(str, '"', 1))
        else str end,
        instr(str, '"', 1) as endpos
    from strings 
    
    union all
    
    select id, 1-lvl, 
        substr(remaining, instr(remaining, '"', 1)+1),
        result || case lvl when 0
            then substr(remaining, 1, instr(remaining, '"', 1)) 
        else
            replace( substr(remaining, 1, instr(remaining, '"', 1)), CHR(13)||CHR(10), CHR(13)||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||CHR(10))
        end ||
        case when instr(substr(remaining, instr(remaining, '"', 1)+1), '"', 1) = 0 then 
            substr(remaining, instr(remaining, '"', 1)+1)
        end,
        instr(substr(remaining, instr(remaining, '"', 1)+1), '"', 1)
    from findquotes
    where endpos > 0
)
select id, result
from findquotes
where endpos = 0
order by id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the fun in 23c:

```
create or replace mle module regexp_mod language javascript as

export function regexp_replace(str, regexp, param, replacestr) {
    var re = new RegExp(regexp, param);
    return str.replace(re, replacestr);
}
/

create or replace function regexp_replace_fnc (
      str string,
      re string, param string, replacestr string)
      return string
    as mle module regexp_mod
    signature 'regexp_replace(string, string,string, string)';
/

with strings(id, str) as (
    select 1, EMPTY_CLOB()|| 'ajktajlt"' || chr(13) || chr(10) || '"zjgljglkJ' from dual union all
    select 2, EMPTY_CLOB()|| 'ajktajlt' || chr(13) || chr(10) || '"zjgljglkJ' from dual union all
    select 3, EMPTY_CLOB()|| 'ajktajlt' || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'zjgljglkJ' from dual union all
    select 4, EMPTY_CLOB()|| 'ajktajlt"' || chr(13) || chr(10) from dual union all
    select 5, EMPTY_CLOB()|| chr(13) || chr(10) || '"zjgljglkJ' from dual 
)
select id, str, 
    regexp_replace_fnc(str, '(["])(\r\n?)\1', 'g', '""') as res
from strings ;
```